# How to evaluate this series using fourier series?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, fourier-series

With the help of **Hermite's Integral**,I got
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n}\int_{2\pi n}^{\infty }\frac{\sin x}{x}\mathrm{d}x=\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(2\pi)$$
I'd like to know can we solve this one using fourier series?

Comment: use the change of variable $x = 2 \pi ny$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We begin with the expression

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\int_{2\pi n}^\infty \frac{\sin (x)}{x}\,dx \tag 1$$

Enforcing the substitution $x \to 2\pi n x$ in $(1)$ yields

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\int_{2\pi n}^\infty \frac{\sin (x)}{x}\,dx&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \int_{1}^\infty \frac{\sin (2\pi nx)}{x}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_{1}^\infty \frac 1x\sum_{n=1}^\infty   \frac{\sin (2\pi nx)}{n}\,dx \tag 2\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{k}^{k+1}\frac1x \left(\frac{\pi}{2}(1-2(x-k))\right)\,dx \tag 3\\\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left((2k+1)\log\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)-2\right) \tag 4\\\\
\end{align}$$

where we recognized the Fourier sine series for $\frac{\pi}{2}(1-2x)$ for $x\in(0,1)$ to go from $(2)$ to $(3)$.

To evaluate the sum in $(4)$, we write the partial sum $S_K$

$$\begin{align}
S_K&=\sum_{k=1}^K \left((2k+1)\log\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)-2\right)\\\\
&=-2K+\sum_{k=1}^K \left((2k+1)\log(k+1)-(2k-1)\log(k)\right)-2\sum_{k=1}^K\log(k) \\\\
&=-2K+(2K+1)\log(K+1)-2\log(K!) \\\\
&=-2K+(2K+1)\log(K)+(2K+1)\log\left(1+\frac1K\right)-2\log\left(K!\right) \tag 5\\\\
&=-2K+(2K+1)\log(K)+2-2\log\left(\sqrt{2\pi K}\left(\frac{K}{e}\right)^K\right)+O\left(\frac1K\right) \tag 6\\\\
&=2-\log(2\pi)+O\left(\frac1K\right)
\end{align}$$

In going from $(5)$ to $(6)$, we used the asymptotic expansion for the logarithm function, $\log(1+x)=x+O(x^2)$ and [Stirling's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)

$$K!=\left(\sqrt{2\pi K}\left(\frac{K}{e}\right)^K\right)\left(1+O\left(\frac1K\right)\right)$$

Finally, putting it all together, we find that

$$\begin{align}
S&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\int_{2\pi n}^\infty \frac{\sin (x)}{x}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\lim_{K\to \infty}S_K\\\\
&=\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}\log(2\pi)
\end{align}$$

and therefore

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\int_{2\pi n}^\infty \frac{\sin (x)}{x}\,dx=\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}\log(2\pi)}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: why we are able to interchange the order of summation and integral at $(2)$?

Comment: @schneiderlog One way is to integrate by parts with $u=1/x$ and $v=-\frac{\cos(2\pi n x)}{2\pi n}$.  Then applying Fubini's Theorem, one can justify the interchange.  After doing this, integrate by parts again with $u=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(2\pi n x)}{2\pi n^2}$ and $v=1/x$.  Now the series is under the integral and we are done.  Another way is to recognize that the integral $\int_1^\infty \frac{\sin(2\pi y)}{x}\,dx$ converges uniformly for all $y\ge \delta>0$.

Comment: Thank you and for (3) do you use the fact that Fourier series of $\frac{\pi}{2}(1-2x)$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}(1-2(x-k))$ are equal?

Comment: The Fourier series has periodic extension.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Observe that
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\sin x}{x} &= \dfrac1x\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{\left(2k+1\right)!}\,x^{2k+1}
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{\left(2k+1\right)!}\,x^{2k}
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\dfrac{1}{n}\int_{2\pi n}^{\infty}\!\!\dfrac{\sin x}{x}\,dx &=
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\dfrac{1}{n}\int_{2\pi n}^{\infty }\!\!\bigg(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{\left(2k+1\right)!}\,x^{2k}\bigg)\,dx 
\\ &=
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\dfrac{1}{n}\bigg(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{\left(2k+1\right)!}\int_{2\pi n}^{\infty}\!\!\!x^{2k}\,dx \bigg)
\\ &=
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\dfrac{1}{n}\bigg(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{\left(2k+1\right)!} \!\cdot\!\left.\dfrac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}\bigg)\right\rvert_{2\pi n}^{\infty}
\\ &=
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\dfrac{1}{n}\Bigg[\bigg(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left.\dfrac{1}{\left(2k+1\right)!}\bigg)\arctan x\,\right\rvert_{2\pi n}^{\infty}\Bigg]
\end{align}

The last equality is due to the series representation of inverse of a tangent  function:

$$
\bbox[1ex, border:solid 1.5pt #e10000]{
\arctan x = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{2k+1}\,x^{2k+1}}
$$

Hope you can proceed from here on.

Comment: This development has serious flaws.  It is incorrect to use a power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n$ to evaluate the integral $\int_a^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n$ by interchanging the integral with the summation.  And $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k\,x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)(2k+1)!} \ne \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\arctan(x)}{(2k+1)!}$.

Comment: @Dr.MV Why is the arctan formula incorrect? Also, what would be a good way to establish or disprove switching order of summation and integration?

Comment: Vlad, the series for the arctangent is indeed $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$.  But one cannot write $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1(2k+1)!}=\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}\right)\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+1)!}$.  And in the case of this solution, the interchange of integration and summation is not justifiable.   -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV Thank you for the explanation! Indeed I made a dumb mistake with arctan series. Just for my own record, why exactly can't we interchange integration and summation signs? Isn't Riemannian integration countably additive? What would be the proper formal argument against changing order of operations?

Comment: If the summation were finite, then of course the interchange of operations is justified.  However, with a series and an integral, the interchange is not generally permissible.  Under sufficient conditions (e.g. dominated convergence, uniform convergence), the interchange of the order of the series and integration is permitted.  In this case, it is obviously not legitimate since prior to the interchange, the improper integral of the sinc function converges.  But after the interchange, none of the terms of the term-by-term integration converge (the upper limit is causing the problem).

Comment: @Dr.MV Thanks again for helping me out. I am going to try to fix my answer, and will delete it within a day if nothing will come to my mind.

Comment: You're welcome, Vlad.  My pleasure.  -Mark

Answer (score 0):

\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \int_{2\pi n}^{\infty} \frac{\sin z}{z } \, {\rm d}z &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin nt}{t +2\pi} \, {\rm d}t \\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \ int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\sin nt}{t + 2 m \pi} \, {\rm d}t \\
&= \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \ int_{0}^{2\pi} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \frac{\sin nt}{t+ 2 m \pi} \, {\rm d }t \\
&= \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\pi -t}{2\left (t + 2 m\pi \right )} \, {\rm d}t\\
&= \pi \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left [ \left ( 1 + \frac{1}{2} \right ) \log \left ( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right ) -1 \right ] \\
&=\pi \log \left [ \lim_{N \rightarrow +\infty} e^{-N} \prod_{ n=1}^{N} \left ( \frac{n+1}{n} \right )^{n+1/2} \right ] \\
&=\pi \log \left ( \lim_{N \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{\sqrt{N+1}\left ( N+1 \right )^N e^{-N}}{N!} \right ) \\
&= \pi \log \left ( \frac{e}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \right ) \\
&= \pi - \frac{ \pi \log 2\pi}{2}
\end{aligned}
since for $t \in (0, 2\pi)$ is $$\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin nt}{n} = \frac{\pi-t}{2}}$$(Fourier series).

Answer (score 0):

[
\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \int_{2n\pi}^\infty \frac{\sin(z)}{z} \, dz \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \int_\pi^\infty \frac{\sin(2nx)}{x} \, dx \\
&= \int_\pi^\infty \frac{1}{x} \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(2nx)}{n}\right) \, dx \\
&= \int_\pi^\infty \frac{1}{x} \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin(2nx) \int_0^\infty e^{-ny} \, dy\right) \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2i} \int_\pi^\infty \frac{1}{x} \int_0^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(e^{-n(y-2ix)} - e^{-n(y+2ix)}\right) \, dy \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2i} \int_\pi^\infty \frac{1}{x} \int_0^\infty \left(\frac{e^{-\left(y-2ix\right)}}{1 - e^{-\left(y-2ix\right)}} - \frac{e^{-\left(y+2ix\right)}}{1 - e^{-\left(y+2ix\right)}}\right) \, dy \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2i} \int_\pi^\infty \frac{1}{x} \int_0^\infty \left(\ln'\left(1 - e^{-\left(y-2ix\right)}\right) - \ln'\left(1 - e^{-\left(y+2ix\right)}\right)\right) \, dy \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2i} \int_\pi^\infty \frac{1}{x} \int_0^\infty \ln'\left(\frac{1 - e^{-\left(y-2ix\right)}}{1 - e^{-\left(y+2ix\right)}}\right) \, dy \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2i} \int_\pi^\infty \frac{1}{x} \ln\left(\frac{1 - e^{2ix}}{1 - e^{-2ix}}\right) \, dx \quad \text{($\left\lfloor * \right\rfloor$)} \\
&= \frac{1}{2i} \int_\pi^\infty \frac{1}{x} \ln\left(e^{i(2x+\pi)}\right) \, dx \quad \text{($\left\lfloor {**} \right\rfloor$)} \\
&= \frac{1}{2i} \int_\pi^\infty \frac{1}{x} i\left(\pi - 2x + 2\pi\left\lfloor\frac{2x}{2\pi}\right\rfloor\right) \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} \frac{1}{x} \left(\pi - 2x + 2n\pi\right) \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} \frac{1}{x} \left(\pi - 2x + 2n\pi\right) \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left((2n+1)\pi\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right) - 2\pi\right) \\
&\Rightarrow \boxed{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \int_{2n\pi}^\infty \frac{\sin(z)}{z} \, dz = \pi \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left((n+\frac{1}{2})\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right) - 1\right)}
\end{aligned}
]

Because
[
$$\left\lfloor * \right\rfloor \ln\left(\frac{1 - e^{2ix}}{1 - e^{-2ix}}\right) = \ln\left(\frac{1 - \cos(2x) - i\sin(2x)}{1 - \cos(2x) + i\sin(2x)}\right) = \ln\left(\frac{-2i\sin(x)e^{ix}}{2i\sin(x)e^{-ix}}\right) = \ln\left(-e^{2ix}\right) = \ln\left(e^{i(2x+\pi)}\right)$$
]

and

$\left\lfloor {**} \right\rfloor: \ln\left(e^{i(2x+\pi)}\right) = i\left(\pi - 2x + 2\pi\left\lfloor\frac{2x}{2\pi}\right\rfloor\right)$
]

because the logarithm is a multivalued function and we have to keep the protean argument which belongs to the interval $\left(-\pi,\pi\right]$. Also,
[
\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{n=1}^N \left((n+\frac{1}{2})\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right) - 1\right) \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^N \ln\left(\frac{{(n+1)^{n+\frac{1}{2}}}}{{e \cdot n^{n+\frac{1}{2}}}}\right) \\
&= \ln\left(\frac{1}{{e^N}} \cdot \frac{{2^1 \cdot 3^2 \cdot \ldots \cdot N^{N-1} \cdot (N+1)^N}}{{1^1 \cdot 2^2 \cdot 3^3 \ldots \cdot N^N}} \cdot (N+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right) \\
&= \ln\left(\frac{1}{{e^N}} \cdot \frac{{(N+1)^N}}{{N!}} \cdot (N+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right) \\
&\Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left((n+\frac{1}{2})\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right) - 1\right) \\
&= \lim_{N\to\infty} \ln\left(\frac{1}{{e^N}} \cdot \frac{{(N+1)^N}}{{N!}} \cdot (N+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right) \\
&= \lim_{N\to\infty} \ln\left(\frac{1}{{\sqrt{2\pi}}} \cdot \left(1+\frac{1}{N}\right)^N\left(\frac{N+1}{N}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right) \\
&= \ln\left(\frac{e}{{\sqrt{2\pi}}}\right)
\end{aligned}
]

Finally,
[
\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \int_{2n\pi}^\infty \frac{\sin(z)}{z} \, dz \\
&= \pi \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left((n+\frac{1}{2})\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right) - 1\right) \\
&= \pi \cdot \ln\left(\frac{e}{{\sqrt{2\pi}}}\right) \\
&= \pi \left(1 - \frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi)\right)
\end{aligned}
]

It is worth noting an initial failed attempt which nevertheless gives (in retrospect) great results.
[
\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \int_{2n\pi}^\infty \frac{\sin(z)}{z} \, dz \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \int_{2n\pi}^\infty \sin(z)\left(\int_0^\infty e^{-zx} \, dx\right) \, dz \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \int_0^\infty \left(\int_{2n\pi}^\infty \sin(z)e^{-zx} \, dz\right) \, dx \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-2n\pi x}}{1 + x^2} \, dx \\
&= \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1 + x^2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-2n\pi x}}{n} \, dx \\
&= -\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln\left(1 - e^{-2\pi x}\right)}{1 + x^2} \, dx \\
&\Rightarrow \boxed{\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln\left(1 - e^{-2\pi x}\right)}{1 + x^2} \, dx = -\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}\ln(2\pi)}
\end{aligned}
]

with continuity

[
\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \int_{2n\pi}^\infty \frac{\sin(z)}{z} \, dz \\
&= -\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln\left(1 - e^{-2\pi x}\right)}{1 + x^2} \, dx \\
&= -\int_0^\infty \ln\left(1 - e^{-2\pi x}\right)\left(\arctan(x)\right)' \, dx \\
&= -\left[\ln\left(1 - e^{-2\pi x}\right)\arctan(x)\right]_0^\infty \\
&+ \int_0^\infty \frac{2\pi e^{-2\pi x}}{1 - e^{-2\pi x}}\arctan(x) \, dx \\
&= 2\pi \int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan(x)}{e^{2\pi x} - 1} \, dx \\
&\Rightarrow \boxed{\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan(x)}{e^{2\pi x} - 1} \, dx = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4}\ln(2\pi)}
\end{aligned}
]

Answer (score 0):

The first observation we make is a simple substitution, with $x=nu$ and $dx=n\;du$:
$$\int_{n\pi}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}x\;dx = \int_{\pi}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nu)}{nu}\;n\;du = \int_{\pi}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}x\;dx$$
Using this identity we can rewrite the given integral as
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1n\int_{n\pi}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}x\;dx = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1n\int_{\pi}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}x\;dx$$
Now (I am causing Fubini to roll over in his grave by doing this) we interchange the sum and integral as follows:
$$\int_{\pi}^{\infty}\left[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}n\right]\;\frac{dx}x$$
To evaluate the sum inside the brackets, we take things into the complex plane. In the following, by $\text{Log}$ and $\text{Arg}$ we refer to the functions with branch cuts along the negative real axis.
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}n &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{inx} - e^{-inx}}{2in} \\
&= \frac1{2i}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{e^{inx}}n - \frac{e^{-inx}}n\right] \\
&= \frac1{2i}\left[-\text{Log}(1-e^{ix}) + \text{Log}(1-e^{-ix})\right] \\
&= \frac1{2i}\left[-\text{log}|1-e^{ix}| - i\text{Arg}(1-e^{ix}) + \text{log}|1-e^{-ix}| + i\text{Arg}(1-e^{-ix})\right] \\
\end{align*}
Since $1-e^{-ix}$ and $1-e^{ix}$ are complex conjugates, we have that their absolute values are equal and their arguments are negatives of each other. So this simplifies to
$$\frac1{2i}\left[2i\text{Arg}(1-e^{-ix})\right] = \text{Arg}(1-e^{-ix})$$
But we're not yet done simplifying. Now we have turned this into a geometry problem: we have a point $X$ on the circle centered at point $C=1$ with radius $1$, whose terminal angle with the [b]negative[/b] real axis (negative because we subtracted from 1) is $x$. Now, supposing for the moment that $0\le x< 2\pi$, and letting $O$ be the origin, the arc subtended by $\angle OCX$ of course has measure $x$. But if we let point $D=2$, then we see that arc $\overarc{XD}$ has signed measure $\pi-x$ (this behaves as expected if $\pi \le x < 2\pi$), and thus inscribed angle $\angle XOD$ has measure $\frac{\pi-x}2$. But this is exactly the argument of $X$! So in summary,
$$\text{Arg}(1-e^{-ix}) = \frac{\pi - (x\mod 2\pi)}2$$
I should mention that things get a little dicey when $x$ is exactly a multiple of $2\pi$. The sum at those points can easily be seen to be zero, since all the sines are zero, but the actual function is discontinuous at those points, approaching $\frac{\pi}2$ from one direction and $-\frac{\pi}2$ from the other. Indeed, the argument is undefined ($\text{Arg}(0)$) there. Fortunately these isolated points are not enough to change the value of the integral. In fact, the next thing we're going to do is split our integral at these points.
\begin{align*}
\int_{\pi}^{\infty}\left[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}n\right]\;\frac{dx}x &= \int_{\pi}^{\infty}\left[\frac{\pi - (x\mod 2\pi)}2\right]\;\frac{dx}x \\
&= \frac12\left[\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} \frac{\pi-(x\mod 2\pi)}x\;dx + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{2n\pi}^{2(n+1)\pi} \frac{\pi-(x\mod 2\pi)}x\;dx\right] \\
&= \frac12\left[\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} \frac{\pi-x}x\;dx + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{2n\pi}^{2(n+1)\pi} \frac{\pi-(x-2n\pi)}x\;dx\right] \\
&= \frac12\left[\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} \left(\frac{\pi}x - 1\right)\;dx + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{2n\pi}^{2(n+1)\pi} \left(\frac{(2n+1)\pi}x-1\right)\;dx\right] \\
&= \frac12\left[\left[\pi\log(x)-x\right]\biggr\rvert_{x=\pi}^{2\pi} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[(2n+1)\pi\log(x)-x\right]\biggr\rvert_{x=2n\pi}^{2(n+1)\pi}\right] \\
&= \frac12\left[\pi\log(2)-\pi + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[(2n+1)\pi\log\left(\frac{2(n+1)\pi}{2n\pi}\right) - 2\pi\right]\right] \\
&= \frac{\pi}2\left[\log(2)-1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[(2n+1)\log\left(\frac{n+1}n\right) - 2\right]\right] \\
&= \frac{\pi}2(\log(2)-1) + \pi\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\left(n+\frac12\right)\log(n+1) - \left(n+\frac12\right)\log(n) - 1\right] \\
\end{align*}
To evaluate the sum, we write it as a limit of a finite sum:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\left(n+\frac12\right)\log(n+1) - \left(n+\frac12\right)\log(n) - 1\right] = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left[\left(n+\frac12\right)\log(n+1) - \left(n+\frac12\right)\log(n) - 1\right]$$
$$= \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left[\frac32\log2 - \frac32\log1 - 1 + \frac52\log3 - \frac52\log2 - 1 + \cdots + \left(N+\frac12\right)\log(N+1) - \left(N+\frac12\right)\log(N) - 1\right]$$
$$= \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left[\left(N+\frac12\right)\log(N+1) - \log(N) - \log(N-1) - \cdots - \log2 - \log1 - N\right]$$
$$= \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left[\left(N+\frac12\right)\log(N+1) - \log(N!) - N\right]$$
And finally, we finish with Stirling's approximation.
\begin{align*}
\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left[\left(N+\frac12\right)\log(N+1) - \log(N!) - N\right] &= \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left[\left(N+\frac12\right)\log(N+1) - \log\left(\sqrt{2\pi N}\left(\frac{N}e\right)^N\right) - N\right] \\
&= \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left[\left(N+\frac12\right)\log(N+1) - \frac12\log(2\pi N) - N\log N + N - N\right] \\
&= \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left[\left(N+\frac12\right)\log(N+1) - \frac12\log(2\pi) - \left(N+\frac12\right)\log N\right] \\
&= -\frac12\log(2\pi) + \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left(N+\frac12\right)\log\left(\frac{N+1}N\right) \\
&= -\frac12\log(2\pi) + \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\left(N+\frac12\right)\log\left(1+\frac1N\right) \\
&= -\frac12\log(2\pi) + \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{N+\frac12}N \\
&= 1 - \frac12\log(2\pi)
\end{align*}
And so, all together, the integral is
$$\frac{\pi}2(\log2-1) + \pi\left[1-\frac12\log(2\pi)\right] = \frac{\pi}2(\log2 - 1 + 2 - \log2 - \log\pi) = \frac{\pi}2(1-\log\pi)$$
Yay, that was fun! $\blacksquare$